# How to execute ABP notifications in parallel?

Tags: c#, notifications, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I'm currently using ASP.NET Boilerplate pattern and it works great. I am able to send notifications without any issues.

The issue I have now is to send LOTS of notifications. Is there any way to execute ABP notifications in parallel or any suggestions to make it execute faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// AppNotifier.cs

public void ContactTransferred(long userId)
{
    var notificationData = new Abp.Notifications.NotificationData();

    _notificationPublisher.Publish(
        AppNotificationNames.ContactTransferredAlert,
        notificationData,
        severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,
        userIds: new long[] { userId }
    );
}
```

```
// Usage

private readonly IAppNotifier _appNotifier;

foreach (Contact c in cList) // cList has 2000+ count
{
    _appNotifier.ContactTransferred(c.Id);
}
```

Comment: Try `HangFire`  https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Hangfire-Integration

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do like this

```
// AppNotifier.cs

public void ContactTransferred(long[] userIdList)
{
    var notificationData = new Abp.Notifications.NotificationData();

    _notificationPublisher.Publish(
        AppNotificationNames.ContactTransferredAlert,
        notificationData,
        severity: NotificationSeverity.Info,
        userIds: userIdList
    );
}
```

---

```
// Usage

private readonly IAppNotifier _appNotifier;

var contactIdList =  cList.Select(c=>c.Id).ToArray();
_appNotifier.ContactTransferred(contactIdList );
```